# How can I use fetchMap() with a RecordMapper?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I know I can fetch a map something like this:

```java
this.ctx.select(
        shopSubscription.field(SHOP_SUBSCRIPTION.SHOP_ID),
        shopSubscription.field(SHOP_SUBSCRIPTION.PAYMENT_GATEWAY_SUBSCRIPTION_ID),
        shopSubscription.field(SHOP_SUBSCRIPTION.ADMIN_TOOL_FEATURE_TYPE_ID),
        PAYMENT_GATEWAY_SUBSCRIPTION.SUBSCRIPTION_ID_TOKEN
        )
    .from(PAYMENT_GATEWAY_SUBSCRIPTION)
        .join(shopSubscription)
            .on(PAYMENT_GATEWAY_SUBSCRIPTION.ID.eq(shopSubscription.field(SHOP_SUBSCRIPTION.PAYMENT_GATEWAY_SUBSCRIPTION_ID))
                    .and(PAYMENT_GATEWAY_SUBSCRIPTION.PAYMENT_GATEWAY_TYPE_ID.eq(paymentGatewayType)))
        .fetchMap(PAYMENT_GATEWAY_SUBSCRIPTION.PAYMENT_GATEWAY_TYPE_ID, ShopSubscriptionDTO.class);
```

but to detect issues at compile time I'd prefer if I could additionally add a `RecordMapper` to this query.

So is there a way to call `fetchMap()` but also provide a `RecordMapper`?

What I'm thinking of would look something like this:

```
this.ctx.select(
        shopSubscription.field(SHOP_SUBSCRIPTION.SHOP_ID),
        shopSubscription.field(SHOP_SUBSCRIPTION.PAYMENT_GATEWAY_SUBSCRIPTION_ID),
        shopSubscription.field(SHOP_SUBSCRIPTION.ADMIN_TOOL_FEATURE_TYPE_ID),
        PAYMENT_GATEWAY_SUBSCRIPTION.SUBSCRIPTION_ID_TOKEN
        )
    .from(PAYMENT_GATEWAY_SUBSCRIPTION)
        .join(shopSubscription)
            .on(PAYMENT_GATEWAY_SUBSCRIPTION.ID.eq(shopSubscription.field(SHOP_SUBSCRIPTION.PAYMENT_GATEWAY_SUBSCRIPTION_ID))
                    .and(PAYMENT_GATEWAY_SUBSCRIPTION.PAYMENT_GATEWAY_TYPE_ID.eq(paymentGatewayType)))

        // For each record apply the map() function

        .map(new RecordMapper<Record<?>, ShopSubscriptionDTO>() {
            @Override
            public ShopSubscriptionDTO map(Record<?> record) {
                ShopSubscriptionDTO shopSubscriptionDto = new ShopSubscriptionDTO();

                shopSubscriptionDto.setShopId(record.getValue(SHOP_SUBSCRIPTION.SHOP_ID)
                // ...

                return shopSubscriptionDto;
            }
        });

        // Fetch the result into a map where the key is SHOP_SUBSCRIPTION.ADMIN_TOOL_FEATURE_TYPE_ID
        .fetchMap(SHOP_SUBSCRIPTION.ADMIN_TOOL_FEATURE_TYPE_ID);
```

Comment: There are `fetchMap()` overloads that accept `RecordMapper` arguments, e.g. [`fetchMap(RecordMapper, RecordMapper)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchMap-org.jooq.RecordMapper-org.jooq.RecordMapper-), but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for. What would you like to do with them?

Comment: @LukasEder What I'm looking for is a way to implement a `RecordMapper` for all values of the resulting `HashMap` in order to convert the selected data into a business object.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not quite sure what that means. Could you perhaps update your question with the expected code / types, etc.?

Comment: @LukasEder Of course :) I've added an example what I think it could look like - I hope this makes sense ^^

Comment: @LukasEder I just found that there is a `fetchMap(Field f, RecordMapper mapper)` .. I didn't see that but I think that's somewhat what I was looking for :D

Comment: Ah, OK I see. Well, feel free to answer your own question, then :)

Comment: @LukasEder I will :) Thanks Lukas!

Answer (score 1):

Since there are quite a lot of different implementations of `fetchMap()` I didn't see that there is `fetchMap(Field<K>, RecordMapper<? super R, R>)` too. So just going with that helps solving this issue:

```java
// ...
.fetchMap(ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON.ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON_TYPE_ID, new RecordMapper<Record, AdminToolAddOnDTO>() {

    @Override
    public AdminToolAddOnDTO map(Record record) {

        AdminToolAddOnDTO dto = new AdminToolAddOnDTO();

        dto.setId(record.getValue(ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON.ID));
        dto.setAdminToolFeatureTypeId(record.getValue(ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON.ADMIN_TOOL_FEATURE_TYPE_ID));
        dto.setAdminToolAddOnTypeId(record.getValue(ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON.ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON_TYPE_ID));
        dto.setPrice(record.getValue(ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON.PRICE));
        dto.setCountryId(record.getValue(ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON.COUNTRY_ID));
        dto.setAddOnIdToken(record.getValue(ADMIN_TOOL_ADD_ON_TYPE.ADD_ON_ID_TOKEN));

        return dto;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

java 8 or higher

```
.fetchMap(CN_TASKS.AGENTID,
                        r -> new CnTaskMessage(r.getValue(CN_TASKS.CN_TASKID), r.getValue(CN_TASKS.TASK_TYPE),
                                r.getValue(CN_TASKS.STATUS)));
```